# Possible Logic Error: remove(vector.begin(),vector.end(),val)

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdvector, erase-remove-idiom

I am looking for a way to delete certain lines in a file. I read on Stack Overflow that the best way to do this is to write it into a vector, and then remove the element from the array, and then read the array back into the file. I was doing this, and was attempting to remove the elements of the array by using the remove method.

I found this method here:

[Removing Method](https://iq.opengenus.org/ways-to-remove-elements-from-vector-cpp/)

But this didn't seem to work, and after compiling their code for myself, I found the theirs didn't work either.

Is there something simple I'm missing? Or is this incorrect. This is their code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    //Insert values 1 to 10
    v.push_back(20);
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(30);
    v.push_back(20);
    v.push_back(40);
    v.push_back(20);
    v.push_back(10);

    vector<int>::iterator new_end;
    new_end = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);

    for(int i=0;i<v.size(); i++){
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    //Prints [10 30 40 10]
    return 0;
}
```

(For further clarification, 'didn't work' means: it printed `20 10 30 20 40 20 10`)

Comment: Unrelated, but please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: As for your problem, please read about [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the for loop like

```
new_end = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);

for ( auto first = v.begin(); first != new_end; first++){
    cout << *first << " ";
}
```

Or you could erase the removed elements like

```
v.erase( new_end, v.end() );
for(int i=0;i<v.size(); i++){
   cout << v[i] << " ";
}
```

or

```
v.erase( new_end, v.end() );
for ( const auto &item : v ){
   cout << item << " ";
}
```

Or you could combine the call of the standard algorithm `std::remove` with the member function `erase` like

```
v.erase( remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 20), v.end() );
```

Pay attention to that if your compiler supports C++ 20 then you can just write

```
std::erase( v, 20 );
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::remove()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) doesn't actually *remove* matching elements from the specified range.  It just moves them to the end of the range, and then returns an `iterator` to the first element that was "removed". You are ignoring that `iterator`.

To physically remove the matching elements from the `std::vector`, you need to call its [`erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) method afterwards, eg:

```
auto new_end = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);
v.erase(new_end, v.end());
```

Otherwise, just use the `iterator` in your loop to stop iterating when you reach the "removed" elements, eg:

```
auto new_end = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);
for(auto iter = v.begin(); iter != new_end; ++iter){
    cout << *iter << " ";
}
```